# The range of the function $f(x) = \frac{(1+x)^4}{1+x^4}$ where $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$

Tags: functions

The range of the function  $f(x) = \frac{(1+x)^4}{1+x^4}$ where $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is _____

Based on desmos.com the range is $[0,8]$

[image]

On solving we get $f'(x) = \frac{-4(x+1)(x-1)(x+1)^2(1+x+x^2)}{(1+x^4)^2}$

We get local minimum at $x=-1$ and local maximumn at $x=1$

Which helps us to get the required range but how we will prove that it is bounded function

Comment: If a continuous function has finite limits at $\infty$ and $-\infty$ then it must be bounded.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x) = \frac{(1+x)^4}{1+x^4}$

$f'(x) = \frac{-4(x+1)(x-1)(x+1)^2(1+x+x^2)}{(1+x^4)^2}$

As, $\frac{(x+1)^2(1+x+x^2)}{(1+x^4)^2}\ge0$ for any value of $x$.

So, $f'(x)<0$ i.e. $f(x)$ is decreasing for $x>1$

$f'(x)>0$ i.e. $f(x)$ is increasing for $x<1$

$\lim_{x\to \pm\infty}\frac{(1+x)^4}{1+x^4}=\lim_{x\to \pm\infty}\frac{(\frac{1}x+1)^4}{1+(\frac{1}x)^4}=1$

So, $f(x)$ is a bounded function.

Hence, one end point of range $f(1)=8$ because function started decreasing from $x=1$ and stoped at $f(x=\infty)=1$. Similarly, another end point of range $f(-1)=0$ because function started increasing from $x=1$ and stoped at $f(x=-\infty)=1$ Therefore, Range of the function is $[f(-1),f(1)]=[0,8]$